# How do you update the counter on button1 when button2 is clicked

Tags: javafx

I have two buttons, button1 contains getMoney() to display the amount of money and button2 that just has a picture of $25 money. When I click button2, it should update button1 to be 25 more. I do this with setMoney() in the handler but although it changes the money variable, on the GUI the amount displayed does not change.

I've tried making the variable static since changing it in one place would change it everywhere. But it still remained the same in the button on the scene. I know the variable changes however because printing it in the console, it increases the money by $25. I've also tried getting the variable directly, to no avail, instead of getMoney() since I believed, when the money variable is changed, it would update it directly. I also tried creating a label and placing that in the button, then in the handler using .setText on the label but that also does not change the amount displayed.

Both buttons are set in this same class. This method sets up the money image. I had to put the StackPane in a Pane to be able to use .setX and .setY on the money image button.

```
public void setup() throws Exception{

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(gameButtons(game.getPlayer(), game));

Pane fullImage = new Pane(root);

Button dollarButton = new Dollar().getDollarButton();
dollarButton.setOnAction(new DollarButtonHandler(game.getPlayer()));
fullImage.getChildren().add(dollarButton);
}
```

The method that creates the dollar counter is this:

```
public static Button getSunCounter(Player aPlayer) throws Exception {
    ImageView bills = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("dollarBills.png")));
    dollarCounter = new Button("Dollars: " + aPlayer.getMoney(), bills);
    return dollarCounter;
}
```

The method that adds the dollar counter is in the gameButtons node.

```
public Node gameButtons(Player aPlayer, Game aGame) throws Exception{
HBox root = new HBox();
root.getChildren().add(getDollarCounter());
return root;
}
```

This is the money image button handler.

```
public class MoneyButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
private Player player;
public MoneyButtonHandler(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    Button source = (Button) event.getSource();     
    player.increaseMoney();
            System.out.println(player.getMoney()); //prints 75, which is correct
ImageView bills = null;
    try {
        bills = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("dollarBills.png")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Button dollarCounter = null;
    try {
        dollarCounter = GardenScene.getDollarCounter(player);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dollarCounter.setText("" + player.getMoney(), bills);//error here, can't put image
//without the 'bills' parameter it still does not change the dollar variable in the GUI
}
}
```

The money variable and its methods are in the player class.

```
public class Player {
private int money = 50;

public Player(int aMoney) {
    this.money = aMoney;
}
public Player() {}

public int getMoney() {
    return this.money;
}
public void increaseMoney() {
    this.money += 25;
}
}
```

Although I am able to change the variable, the change isn't displayed in the GUI. 
I updated my code to show how I tried to use .setText() but that problem is that I can no longer add the image to the dollarCounter, as well when I don't take adding the image into account, it still does not change the counter displayed.

I am using a Button and not a Label since I would need the Label to be in a rectangle and with an image and I don't know how to do that with a Label but I can look into it. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where are you attempting to change the text on the `Button`? I don't see any call to `dollarCounter.setText()`.

Comment: **Side Note:** Generally speaking, a `Button` shouldn't be used to display information, but to trigger an action. What is the purpose of your `dollarCounter`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Zephyr. I just edited my post to attempt that but it still does not work, as well I added information at the end to why I used a Button. The purpose of my dollarCounter is just to display the money the player has left, thus what they can afford to buy in a rectangle.

Comment: Assuming `getDollarCounter()` is actually `getSunCounter()`, this method creates and returns a **new** button. You need to set the text of the **existing, displayed** button. Not of a new button that isn't displayed anywhere.

Comment: @ JB Nizet Yes it is, sorry I didn't refactor that. But that makes sense, thanks so much!